# Are bindings automatically removed in a TreeCell

Tags: java, javafx-8

I have TreeView that has a cell factory set on it. The TreeCells I'm returning are displayed below:

```
import javafx.beans.binding.StringBinding;
import javafx.collections.ObservableMap;
import javafx.scene.control.TreeCell;

public class TreeCellTest extends TreeCell<String> {
    private ObservableMap<String, StringBinding> lookup;

    public TreeCellTest(ObservableMap<String, StringBinding> lookup) {
        this.lookup = lookup;
    }

    @Override
    protected void updateItem(String id, boolean empty) {
        super.updateItem(id, empty);
        if (empty) {
            setText(null);
        } else {
            StringBinding stringBinding = lookup.get(id);
            textProperty().bind(stringBinding);
        }
    }
}
```

Notice that I'm not setting the text but I'm binding the textProperty to a StringBinding. This works fine in normal situations but I'm wondering if it is OK to use it inside a TreeCell.

The TreeCell gets recycled as and when needed so I would like to know whether when this happens the binding gets automatically removed or whether I need to remove it manually?

I don't want the case where each TreeCell has 100's of bindings attached to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While it's not documented, it appears that calling `bind(...)` will remove any existing bindings before creating the new binding.

For example:

```
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleStringProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.StringProperty;


public class RebindingTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        StringProperty text = new SimpleStringProperty();
        StringProperty value1 = new SimpleStringProperty();
        StringProperty value2 = new SimpleStringProperty();

        text.addListener((obs, oldValue, newValue) -> System.out.printf("text changed from %s to %s%n", oldValue, newValue));
        text.bind(value1);

        value1.set("Set value 1");
        text.bind(value2);
        value2.set("Set value 2");
        value1.set("Reset value 1");

    }
}
```

So I think all you need to do to make your code work correctly is add

```
textProperty().unbind();
```

to the `if (empty) { ... }` block.

Of course, calling that unconditionally in your `updateItem(...)` method would mean you're not relying on undocumented behavior, and any loss of efficiency is probably minimal.

Comment: Of course, I'll just call textProperty().unbind(); each time the update method is called - I didn't think of that - Thanks